# Two short stays days apart in Thailand (British Passport)

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, thailand

I have a British Passport and I want to fly from HeHo (Myanmar) to Chiang Mai (Thailand), spend a few days there, fly to Luang Prebang (Laos), spend a four or so days there and then fly to Bangkok (Thailand) from Vientiane (Laos). When I arrive in Bangkok I will stay for four days before returning home on a flight.

Will I be okay with getting a Visa Waiver when I arrive each time, or should I do something in advance?

I did email the embassy but I got a canned reply that didnt quite provide the detail or the confidence I needed that all would be well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and did this trip, there was no problem getting entry to Thailand at each new entry.

It may differ if they are same-day but for short excursions to Laos and back to Thailand there was no trouble or questions